# Unhandled promise rejection thrown in afterAll for Karma only after node upgrade

Tags: javascript, node.js, karma-runner

How to solve unhandled promise rejection error in karma unit test?

```
Chrome Headless 102.0.5005.115 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
  Unhandled promise rejection: [object Object] thrown
  Unhandled promise rejection: [object Object] thrown
Chrome Headless 102.0.5005.115 (Linux x86_64): Executed 1 of 23 ERROR (0.03 secs / 0.016 secs)
```

this is the error I am getting when karma unit test is run on docker.
There are no error when I tran same test on local karma.

local node v16.14.2

docker node v16.15.0

This error started coming when I upgraded docker node from `v10.20.1` to `v16.15.0`

I am most certain that issue is in project js file itself but how to find the error cause. Please help!
docker npm list:

```
npm list --depth=0
development_environment@1.0.0 /usr/src/app
+-- @babel/core@7.18.6
+-- @babel/preset-env@7.18.6
+-- eslint-config-plato@1.0.6
+-- eslint@8.19.0
+-- express@4.18.1
+-- fs-extra@10.1.0
+-- gulp-babel@8.0.0
+-- gulp-clean-css@4.3.0
+-- gulp-eslint@6.0.0
+-- gulp-header@2.0.9
+-- gulp-htmlhint@4.0.2
+-- gulp-replace@1.1.3
+-- gulp-sass@5.1.0
+-- gulp@4.0.2
+-- http-proxy-middleware@2.0.6
+-- jquery-mockjax@2.6.0
+-- karma-chrome-launcher@3.1.1
+-- karma-coverage@2.2.0
+-- karma-es6-shim@1.0.0
+-- karma-firefox-launcher@2.1.2
+-- karma-jasmine-jquery-2@0.1.1
+-- karma-jasmine@5.1.0
+-- karma-junit-reporter@2.0.1
+-- karma-requirejs@1.1.0
+-- karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter@0.0.23
+-- karma@6.4.0
+-- requirejs@2.3.6
+-- sass@1.53.0
`-- through2@4.0.2
```

Please guide if the question needs improvement. Thank you!

Comment: If you install Node 16.5.0 on your local machine, do you get the same error? That will be easier debugging than on a docker instance. 

Can you post some code? What is going on in that `afterAll()`?

Comment: No error could not be generated on local node. There is no afterAll() in code at all. It might be somewhere inside Karma

Comment: Did you reinstall all your dependencies? Because some packages may have dependencies to the node binaries which may break between major versions of nodejs.

Comment: Yes @derpirscher By upgrading node on docker image I meant using whole new image.

Answer (score 1):

You're possibly running into [this issue](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1917) on `jasmine` a dependency of `karma`. They had changed their error detection logic so that it started reporting unhandled rejections that previously weren't.

> So it applies a simple rule: whenever control is returned to the runtime, an unhandled rejection event is fired for every promise that has been rejected and not awaited (or .then-d)

Even though you have a recent Node version, you maybe have a version of the dependency from before this behavior was introduced.

If I understood correctly, you should be able to fix it in your tests by ensuring all rejected promises are handled before the test returns.

One [suggested fix](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1917#issuecomment-861915311):

> You could try explicitly handling the rejection immediately after
> creating the promise:
>
> ```
>     const rejectingPromise = Promise.reject(new Error("Operation failed."));
>     rejectingPromise.catch(() => {});
>     await new Promise<void>((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
>     // [...]
> ```

The exact fix will depend on how the test that causes this looks like, but I guess you'll always be able to do something similar.

###### Update

This kind of fix didn't seem to work for the code of the original question, but might in other cases.

Comment: This also didn't work. No change in the error.

Comment: @MujeebShaikh Can you disable all your tests, re-enable them one by one, and then post the code of the first test that causes the error here?

Comment: each and every test individually gave `An error was thrown in afterAll  Unhandled promise rejection: [object Object] thrown` error and the answer  which I posted is the first test of 23.